# Windows workflow foundation and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow-foundation-4

I am going to develop an easy workflow application using C#. I am planning to use Windows workflow foundation technology and develop it as an ASP.net web application.

1. As i read in some web sites in order to invoke windows workflow foundation with asp.net, it should be used the MVC approach. Is it possible to do it without the MVC approach?
2. You have to consider that i have no experience with MVC approach. Is it more easy to develop it as Windows forms application instead of using ASP.NET?

Comment: BTW, which web sites suggest you need MVC? Post a link.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't have to use ASP.NET MVC with Windows Workflow Foundation.

If you've never worked with ASP.NET MVC before, you'll probably find the initial learning curve to be quite steep. But there is plenty of help to be found online.
Developing it in Windows Forms or ASP.NET Webforms may be easier for you, depending on your level of experience.

Answer (score 2):

When you say you want to develop a Workflow as an ASP.NET Web Application I assume you mean that you want to create a workflow that runs on a web server and is accessible as a web service.

In that case, we call those "Workflow Services" and you do not need to learn ASP.NET MVC to create them.  I suggest you download the [Visual Studio 2010 training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=752CB725-969B-4732-A383-ED5740F02E93&displaylang=en)  and spend some time going through the Introduction To Workflow Services Hands On Lab.